# how to count all empty cells in a table with knexjs?

Tags: knex.js

I've a table that has multiple rows, each row has empty cells, I'm trying to get count all empty cells in each row as a total.

table schema id , name, colmn1 , colmn2, colmn3, colmn4, etc.... till colmn20

I've tried doing something like this

```
knexDb('users').where(function() {
    this.where('colmn1', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn2', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn3', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn4', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn5', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn6', '=', '')
    .orWhere('colmn7', '=', '')
    .orWhere(........ etc till colmn20
  })
  .map(function(row) {
    // console.log(row)
    var emptycolmns = 0;
    if(row.colmn1 === ''){
      emptycolmns++
    }else if (row.colmn2 === ''){
      emptycolmns++
    }else if ....... etc till colmn20
  })
  .then(rows => {
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(emptycolmns);
  })
```

but this didn't work for me.

**PS**. as you can see it's not good to hard code all columns, is there is a better way to achieve both results, with better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of to count columns with empty strings would be something like:

```
knex.raw(
  `select (col1='') + (col2='') + (col3='') as empty_cols from foo`
)
```

Here you're relying on the fact that each expression will resolve to an integer, so at the end you'll get a result like:

```
empty_cols
==========
1
3
2
3
1
```

As you point out, it doesn't seem too flexible, but it's hard to advise on a preferred schema without knowing more about the problem.